# How to type number or lower letter in CasperJS using PhantomJS' sendEvent function

Tags: javascript, keyboard, phantomjs, casperjs

I am sure someone has asked it before, and I just spent couple hours finding answers, but most people are entering 'enter' key in CasperJS.

i am able to type a "A" - "Z" , but no response on "a"-"z" and "1"-"9".
here is what I try:

```
casper.then(function (){
  this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.F);
  this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.c);
  this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.4);

  console.log('there is only F.. but no c and 4');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the others, because PhantomJS uses only uppercase strings (`F`) to define letters `f` from `page.event.key.F` ([source](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/cab2635e66d74b7e665c44400b8b20a8f225153a)).

```
casper.page.sendEvent("keypress", casper.page.event.key.F);
```

should give you a lowercase F: `f`. If you want to type uppercase characters in this way then you need to pass in a modifier ([documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html))

```
casper.page.sendEvent('keypress', casper.page.event.key.F, null, null, 0x02000000);
```

Variables in JavaScript must not begin with a digit, so `this.page.event.key.4` *cannot* be used to access a property that begins with a digit. If you want to type a `4`, you need to use the string syntax: `this.page.event.key["4"]`.

---

This is pretty cumbersome. Why don't you just use a string to type those characters?

```
casper.page.sendEvent("keypress", "Fc4");
```